# Get least significant bytes from an integer

Tags: java

I need to sum all data bytes in `ByteArrayOutputStream`, adding +1 to the result and taking the 2 least significant bytes.

```
    int checksum = 1;
    for(byte b : byteOutputStream.toByteArray()) {
        checksum += b;
    }
```

Any input on taking the 2 least significant bytes would be helpful. Java 8 is used in the environment.

Comment: you should be able to use a mask and bitwise and to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you really mean least significant bytes then:

```
checksum & 0xFFFF
```

If you meant that you want to take least significant *bits* from checksum, then:

```
checksum & 0x3
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
checksum &= 0x0000ffff;
```

That will zero out everything to the left of the 2 least significant bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit underspecified. You didn’t say neither, what you want to do with these two bytes nor how you want to store them (which depends on what you want to do).

To get to individual bytes, you can use

```
byte lowest = (byte)checksum, semiLowest=(byte)(checksum>>8);
```

In case you want to store them in a single integer variable, you have to decide, how these bytes are to be interpreted numerically, i.e signed or unsigned.

If you want a signed interpretation, the operation is as simple as

```
short lowest2bytes = (short)checksum;
```

If you want an unsigned interpretation, there’s the obstacle that Java has no dedicated type for that. There is a 2 byte sized unsigned type (`char`), but using it for numerical values can cause confusion when other code tries to interpret it as character value (i.e. when printing). So in that case, the best solution is to use an `int` variable again and only initialize it with the unsigned `char` value:

```
int lowest2bytes = (char)checksum;
```

Note that this is semantically equivalent to

```
int lowest2bytes = checksum&0xffff;
```

seen in other solutions.